# Dealing with White Space for hrefs with windows folder paths in Google Earth

Tags: windows, kml

I am using Google Earth to generate a KML file with placemarks generated from autocad drawings.
These placemarks each contain a href to the windows folder location of the drawing.
So far this works fine in most instances except the problem I face is dealing with whitespace in the windows file paths.

eg. S:/job/13/13347/item 1/

I am aware of the Windows 8.3 aliasing for file paths containing white space.

But was wondering if there was another way to code the file path other than using the

~1 convention as this would be difficult to code and and would produce inconsistent results.

I am creating the kml file from and ArcGIS shapefile using ESRI arc view

cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

URL escaped space is `%20`, so `S:/job/13/13347/item%201/` should work

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried this and while it works if you cut and paste this into a windows browser, it does not work as a href from the KML file

Comment: Why do you want to escape them if you paste them in windows explorer? It will work fine with spaces in windows explorer.

Comment: Except that you have forward-slashes and windows take back-slashes, but I assume you are aware of that.

Comment: Hi @valentinas thanks for your input I believe this may be a bug in Google Earth as indicated by this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903600/google-earth-will-not-open-links-in-kml-that-have-spaces/13833164#13833164