# Referencing local images in KML results in inconsistent behavior

Tags: python, kml, google-earth

My goal is to create a KML that contains links to photos with GPS information on a set of network drives. Generate the file with Python and create the paths using `pathlib.Path(...).as_uri()`.

For example, this would be created:

```
    <Placemark>
      <name>IMG_0089</name>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[
        <img src="file:////share/folder%201/folder2/IMG_0089.JPG" width="600"/> 
        ]]>
      </description>
      <styleUrl>#simpleBalloon</styleUrl>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>-122.5,37.2</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
```

I have a couple questions:

First, the URI provided by `pathlib` starts with `file://`, however it seems that Google Earth wants the path to start with `file:////`. Chrome will open `file://` just fine.

Second, not all of the images are displayed by Google Earth. I can take the path in the KML and open it in Chrome (or Windows Explorer) and the image is displayed. What is most confusing is that it only happens on some images. The paths are being quoted by `Jinja2` when the KML is created.

Based on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16880375/562934), it appears this this might be related to how some characters should be escaped. At least some of the problematic paths have apostrophes in them.

Comment: If you put the KML file in the "share" drive then the images can be referenced with relative links and won't need the file: prefix.

Comment: The file prefix is not the issue, but rather how Google Earth processes the URIs. Some of the URIs work, others don't.

Comment: Post examples of the problem paths where image are not displaying. Having special characters in path names (whitespace, apostrophes, etc.) can be tricky. Do you have the option to rename the folder names to not have special chars?

Comment: You have two situations going on here: 1) KML references on network drive with absolute URLs file:// vs file:////, etc.; and 2) special chars (e.g. whitespace and apostrophes) in the folder names. Suggest you start simple by putting KML on same level as the network drive; make folders have simple names; make image references in KML relative; then verify all images can be accessed. After that can address special cases.

Comment: @JasonM1 I agree. Unfortunately, this is a shared drive that is organized by a team of folks so I don't want to move files around to solve this issue. The solution that I am considering is to create thumbnails of images with a simple path that can be handled by Google Earth and then provide a link that can be opened with Windows Explorer to the full resolution image. More than anything, I am surprised that Google Earth cannot handle complex path names when Chrome has no issue.

Comment: GE Pro is fine with the standard stuff but when combining nonsense paths; e.g. file://// with special chars in file names and paths then can lead to some rare combination that was never tested and doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Two issues are coming up here.

1. The images are on a shared drive and your KML is on the local drive with absolute URLs using `file:////` for the prefix. Recommend putting the KML on same drive and root path as the images and use relative paths to the images from the KML. Access to local files may be disabled by default so if that is needed then navigate to Tools > Options > General and check "Allow access to local files and personal data".
2. Special characters (whitespace and apostrophes) are in the folder names and/or file names. This requires escaping the URLs and sometimes doesn't work as expected.

In general, special characters in paths and filenames SHOULD work in Google Earth Pro BUT some combinations of special characters and/or URLs with absolute paths to external drive may have issues that can take some time to troubleshoot.

If possible it is best to **keep it simple** by 1) placing the KML on the same drive/location as the images being referenced or bundle the images inside KMZ with the KML and use relative URL references, and 2) sanitize the folder and file names to not include special characters.

Once the KML is working as you expect it, then you can experiment with putting the KML file and/or images on a shared drive or rename file and/or path names to include special characters.